# how can I put pop equel to true value in the If

Tags: python, if-statement

when I run my code I face this error
"name 'pop' is not defined" how can I solve it?

```
if(pop() == True):
    pass
else:
   Deleted_trial = frames_id.pop(0)
```

Comment: What did you expect that `pop()` is?

Comment: I had a nested list in Jupyter and I want to remove the first item, but I want to do it once and not repeat it each time that I run the block. so I change it like this

Comment: Why don't you remove the item before you run the block repeatedly? (not when inside the block)

Comment: I need to write a code to avoid mistake for the next person who uses it. I divided the code and put the pop part in another block but still by mistake someone run that block more than one time.

Comment: Have you tried setting a variable `pop = True` after executing `frames_id.pop(0)`? Then use `if pop: pass`.

Comment: You'll need to define a function called *pop()*

Answer (score 0):

the pop method removes an item from a list and returns that value.  So if you have a list of boolean values, this would work if you used the pop method on that list...

i.e. `if(boolList.pop() == True)...`

Learn more at https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/pop